# setting shared schema for multiple fastify routes

Tags: fastify

I have the following route

```js
export default async function (fastify) {
  // fastify routes here...
  fastify.get(
    '/',
    {
      schema: {
        params: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            id: {
              type: 'number',
              description: 'configuration id',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    async (req) => {
      console.log(req.params);
      return {};
    },
  );
}

// Prefix for fastify autoload
export const autoPrefix = `/configuration/:id/jobs`;
```

How can I set the parameter schema for all of my routes in that function so I don't to duplicate my param schema:

```js
{
  params: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      id: {
        type: 'number',
        description: 'configuration id',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I know I can do:

```js
const params = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      description: 'configuration id',
    },
  },
};
fastify.get(
  '/',
  {
    schema: {
      params,
    },
  },
  async (req) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    return {};
  },
);
```

But asking if there is a way that I won't need to do that for each route

---

Edit: I've opened an issue with a proposal [fastify/fastify#4316](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/4316)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`onRoute` hook](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/docs/Reference/Hooks.md#onroute)

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

const params = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      description: 'configuration id'
    }
  }
}

fastify.addHook('onRoute', function hook (routeOptions) {
  if (!routeOptions.schema) {
    routeOptions.schema = {}
  }

  if (!routeOptions.schema.params && routeOptions.path.includes(':id')) {
    routeOptions.schema.params = params
  }
})

fastify.get('/:id', async (request, reply) => {
  return { hello: 'world' }
})
fastify.register(async function plugin (instance, opts) {
  instance.post('/foo', async (request, reply) => {
    return request.body
  })
}, { prefix: '/:id' })

fastify.ready()
```

Comment: Thanks!, if it's coming from a fastify maintainer (Highly appreciate your work)! it's probably means that there is no better way that is more developer friendly...

Comment: What do you mean by "developer friendly"? There are tons of options available like loading a schema file named as the route url, but under the hood this magic plugin must use the onroute hook to set the schema parameter. Do you want to define a convention over configuration pattern on your application?